# Where should I put the word "would" (for repeated past actions) in a sentence with more clauses?

Tags: past-simple

I'd like to know where the word "would" should be used in a sentence with more clauses, like the following. 
Among the examples, I'd choose the first one, as "I" is the main subject who performs the action on which the sentence focuses.

> 1) When my friends invited me to parties, I **would** always reply with a
>   no.
>
> 2) When my friends **would** invite me to parties, I **would** always
>   reply with a no.
>
> 3) When my friends **would** invite me to parties, I always replied with
>   a no.

Comment: When a question is put on hold, please don't delete it and re-post it.  Instead, work toward getting the original reopened.  In this case, I can see that you've edited your question to address the reason it was closed, so I'm going to go ahead and reopen it.  In the future, if you feel a moderator has closed your question in error, please free to flag it so we can review it and take whatever action is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The word **when** can mean **whenever**, as in your example sentences. So your context involves a  regular, recurrent, or usual practice, where it was your *wont* to say no to invitations.

**will** and past tense **would** can express the regular or the usual, a *wont*. You are using it correctly in that regard.

There are two actions involved in your context, the invitation and the reply. Both can be expressed as regular, recurrent, or usual, something that happened from time to time, and so *grammatically* you could use **would** with each: they would invite you and you would say no. However, *semantically* it is *your* wont that is the focus of the utterance, and so for that reason you'd want to make sure that there was something in that clause that expresses *wont*.

The phrase  **always said|always replied** certainly expresses *wont*. The phrase **would always say** does so too.  And the simple **would say** does so as well.  Which to say is a stylistic choice.

There is a principle in communications theory which says that redundancy is good, since it improves the chances of a message being received and understood even if something is lost "in transmission".  If you let that be your guide, **would always say** or **would always reply** is the winner.